# Rails testing failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I am having and issue with one of my rails tests. Below is the test that is failing but shout not be.

```
setup do
  @answer = Answer.new(:title => 'Title', :body => 'Body', :email => 'you@me.com', :quiz_id => 1, :user_id => 1)
end

test 'should not save answer with missing email' do
  @answer.email = nil
  assert !@answer.save, 'answer was saved'
end
```

I am checking to make sure the saving fails with !@answer.save but this is not working the results are a bad test with the following error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'email' cannot be null:
```

I want my test to not save when there is a missing email. Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please post the code which contains the validation. Does it work as expected when tested manually, e.g. via a browser?

Comment: My model does not validate the presence of email because it is not a form field. Its the schema that is set to not have the field be null :null => false

Comment: Rails is behaving as expected. Your spec could verify that the ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid exception is thrown, but it's probably better to add a validation, as Sam suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `email` column in your MySQL table has been set to not allow null values.

The migration to create the `answers` table will have something like `t.string :email, :null => false`.

You will need to create a validation to stop the model from trying to save and triggering the MySQL error.

Try,

```
validates_presence_of :email
```

This will stop the model from saving and give you an Active Record validation error message instead.

**EDIT:**

You will need the validation if you cannot guarantee there will always be an email value. If you can guarantee there will always be an email value, your test on the model is unnecessary because you can guarantee this scenario will never happen.

You may want to test the code that calls this code to ensure it always supplies an `email` value to the `Answer.new` method.